# Excel how to count text in cells considering a range of dates in other columns

Tags: excel, date

I am trying to make an excel file with the leaves of some guys at work. We have 3 kinds of leaves. K, ET and T. But we always have to check how many everyone has been left with. i.e. everyone can take 12 ET days. 
My main question is if I can sum up the total days taken till todays date. Was thinking of a way to link the top row that is date with the cell that contains the type of leave. The total sum is calculated but the "days taken till this moment" made me crazy. Thanks

http://prntscr.com/f9rp73

http://prntscr.com/f9rpl1

Comment: I think it's clear on the second screenshot what I have. All I need is a sum of "K" days from 1/1 till TODAY only. Not a specific date, but only today

Answer (score 0):

Replace the formula in E4 from `=countif(I4:JF4,"K")` to `=COUNTIFS(H4:JF4,E$3,H$3:JF$3,"<"&TODAY())`

If you want to count all Et, K and T days till today you can copy down and acroos this formula or if you want only calculate "K" days till today you can copy it down.